# Convert the last non-zero value to 0 for each row in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to modify my data frame in a way that the last variable of a label encoded feature is converted to 0. For example, I have this data frame, top row being the labels and the first column as the index:

```
df
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
```

Columns 1-10 are the ones that have been encoded. What I want to convert this data frame to, without changing anything else is:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

So the last values occurring in each row should be converted to 0. I was thinking of using the last_valid_index method, but that would take in the other remaining columns and change that as well, which I don't want. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What about row 0, col 2? Shouldn't that be 0 too?

Comment: No, because it isn't the last value. Row 0 column 10 is the last value for that row, which gets converted to 0. I have other rows after column 10 which I don't want changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to build a boolean mask, and set to zero.

```
v = df.cumsum(axis=1)
df[v.lt(v.max(axis=1), axis=0)].fillna(0, downcast='infer')

   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

---

Another similar option is reversing before calling `cumsum`, you can now do this in a single line.

```
df[~df.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(1).le(1)].fillna(0, downcast='infer')

   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

If you have more columns, just apply these operations on the slice. Later, assign back.

```
u = df.iloc[:, :10]
df[u.columns] = u[~u.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(1).le(1)].fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Comment: Well the issue with this is it would take the entire data frame, which has more columns after column 10, I think you edited that out of my original post

Comment: @codingenthusiast Correct. Because I did not want it to detract from the intent of your question. I will add in an edit to address that.

Comment: @codingenthusiast Done.